# How do I get ability scores with dice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

My friends and i have always decided on the ability scores using a random number generator app from 12-17 because we cant really find the right way to generate the numbers with dice. so my question is, how many dice and what kind of dice do we use?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to generate ability scores and they really depend on the preferences of your group. This question may be a bit too broad. Have you tried the solutions offered in the PHB?

Comment: Yes, can you not find the appropriate rules, do they not make sense, or are you looking for an alternative, and if so, what goal are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to generate numbers specifically between 12 and 17 using dice? If so I would recommend changing the question in your title to something like "How can I generate ability scores within a specific range using dice?"

Answer (score 6):

The Core Rulebook offers, on page 15, five different ways to come up with ability scores.

The one I would say is most common is the first one listed. To generate one score, roll 4 six-sided die, drop the lowest, and add the other three. So, if you rolled 2, 5, 6, and 2, you'd drop one of the 2's and get a score of 13. Repeat six times, then assign those numbers to whatever stats you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The [D20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores) lists the methods of generating ability scores in Pathfinder.

There are several different dice-rolling schemes, or point-buy.